# Create new column based on information in two other columns

Tags: conditional-statements

I have a data frame with 2 columns of information that I want to compare to create a new condition in a new column.

| PPT | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | A | 2 |
| 3 | A | 3 |
| 4 | B | 1 |
| 5 | B | 2 |
| 6 | B | 3 |
| 7 | C | 1 |
| 8 | C | 2 |
| 9 | C | 3 |

I want the new column to provide a categorisation based on columns 1 and 2 using the following criteria:

if A equals 1, column 3 should be YES
if B equals 2, column 3 should be YES
if C equals 3, column 3 should be YES
All other instances, column 3 should be NO

| PPT | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | YES |
| 2 | A | 2 | NO |
| 3 | A | 3 | NO |
| 4 | B | 1 | NO |
| 5 | B | 2 | YES |
| 6 | B | 3 | NO |
| 7 | C | 1 | NO |
| 8 | C | 2 | NO |
| 9 | C | 3 | YES |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 0):

Make a mask with all of your conditions, and then you can make a new column set to 'NO' and change all valid rows to 'YES'

```py
# Find rows where conditions are True
mask = ((df['1'] == 'A') & (df['2'] == 1)) | ((df['1'] == 'B') & (df['2'] == 2)) | ((df['1'] == 'C') & (df['2'] == 3))

# Create new column using rows
df['3'] = 'NO'
df.loc[mask, '3'] = 'YES'
```